# I don't know what's wrong with my IPhone 5C

Tags: iphone

My phone has been acting up. It turns on and off by itself. My apps also freeze and crash. Im not even able to back up my phone because every time I do it, it cancels. I turn my phone on and off all the time and I restart it (by pressing the home button and power button at the same time) and it's no help at all. I was thinking about resetting my phone but I'm afraid it won't work. I need help. I don't know what I should do.

Comment: as long you know your password (Apple ID) go ahead and reset it.

Comment: At First try to replace the battery this usually sorts certain problems. Just remember to heat up the back just before you pry out battery and pry on the side with the volume keys not the logicboard side

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset your iPhone, maybe first you should backup your data. You can try to backup your data on iCloud, and then restore your iPhone. Unfortunately, you said that you can not back up every time, can you connect it with your PC? If you still can't backup data, you can try to restore your iPhone 5c directly and see how it goes. Don't be afraid. Good luck.

Comment: Fair approach but it's sadly a guess, not a for-sure solution.